# Storing and indexing large trajectory dataset generated by cars' GPS

Tags: postgis, trajectory, indexing

I have a large trajectory dataset generated by cars' GPS. Since I will do some data mining work on them, I need an efficient way to store and index them.
I read some papers about ***Trajectory Indexing*** (***Computing with Spatial Trajectories, by Yu Zheng and Xiaofeng Zhou, Microsoft research Asia***), 3D R-tree, TB-tree(Trajectory-Bundle tree), SETI(Scalable and Efficient Trajectory Index) were proposed to solve this problem. But it is quite difficult to implement them.

Is there any implementation on this problem?

I am not quite familiar with PostGIS. It has R-tree, but trajectories have a "time" dimension.

Could I expand postGis to index trajectories?

How?

1,2000 taxis' trajectories for one month. About 50GB. latitude,longtitude,time. I need to search for trajectories of regions during anytime, and so on.